# Pulling categorized entries in a category loop

Tags: categories, craft3

I am trying to pull channel entries and display them using a loop. These entries would then be organized by the category they are assigned to based on a categoryfield a user selects when creating the entry. Below is the code I am beginning with.

```
{% set category = entry.myCategoriesField.first() %}
{% if category %}
 {% for car in craft.entries.section('category')%}
  **Might need a set option here for entries??**

  {{car.Title}}
  {{car.carDescription}}

 {%endfor%}
{% endif %}
```

Should look like:

Car

- Prius: {{Description}}

Truck

- Ram {{Description}}
- Silverado{{Description}}

SUV

- Suburban {{Description}}
- Escape {{Description}}

Any thoughts or direction would be helpful.

I have looked into the following code but don't think it would work the way I want to.

```
{% set category = entry.myCategoriesField.first() %}
{% if category %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have part of the solution which is to use:

```
{% set categories = entry.categoriesFieldHandle %}
{% if categories | length %}

<h3>Some great categories</h3>
{% nav category in categories %}
    {%for entry%}
    {%endfor%}

{% endnav %}
{% endif %}
```

Just now need to find out how to add the Category Title in and work on separating the entries out.